# How to set the pygame icon to an online image

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

So let's say I have a URL that stores an image, let's say it's, `"https://www.image.site/img.png"`
I want to set the pygame icon to that image without downloading anything on my computer.

I am already familiar with the code to set the icon to a file on your computer

```py
img = pygame.image.load('image')
pygame.display.set_icon(img)
```

But how can I set it to an online image, would just setting the argument in set_icon to the URL work, or do I have to do something more complicated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way:

- Use the **requests** library to download the image bytes
- Use **BytesIO** to create a file stream in memory
- Create a **PIL.Image** from the byte file stream
- Use **pygame.image.fromstring** to convert the PIL image to a pygame image

Here's the code:

```
import pygame
from io import BytesIO
import requests
from PIL import Image

# create image from URL
rsp = requests.get('https://www.pygame.org/docs/_static/pygame_tiny.png')
pilimage = Image.open(BytesIO(rsp.content)).convert("RGBA")
pgimg = pygame.image.fromstring(pilimage.tobytes(), pilimage.size, pilimage.mode)

# show image
pygame.init()
display = pygame.display.set_mode((250,150))

display.fill((255,255,255))
display.blit(pgimg,((250 - pgimg.get_rect().width)/2,(150 - pgimg.get_rect().height)/2))
pygame.display.update()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit(); exit()
```

Output

[image: Pygame]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you'd do that, but I cooked something up for you.

It downloads the data of an image and then loads an image out of that data.

```
import requests
import io

import pygame

def surf_from_url(url):
    data = io.BytesIO()

    response = requests.get(url, stream=True)      
    if not response.ok:
        print(response)

    for block in response.iter_content(1024):
        if not block:
            break

        data.write(block)

    data.seek(0)
    return pygame.image.load(data)

    
#demo

surf = surf_from_url("https://www.pygame.org/images/logo_lofi.png")
surf2 = surf_from_url("https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJxybFq6Y8SFOuyvWqldJPcXbCps-gR_Qp2z4jKt=s100-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo")

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([300,300])

pygame.display.set_icon(surf)
screen.fill((255,255,255))

screen.blit(surf, (0,0))
screen.blit(surf2, (20,100))

pygame.display.flip()
```